# How to make right Active Record Associations between many models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to make product catalog. And I can't understand how to make right associations.

This is my schema.rb:

```
  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "name",            limit: 50, null: false
    t.integer "product_type_id"
  end

  create_table "product_types", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", limit: 20, null: false
  end

  create_table "product_specs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name",       limit: 20, null: false
    t.string "value_type", limit: 20
  end

  create_table "product_specs_types", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "product_type_id", null: false
    t.integer "product_spec_id", null: false
  end
  add_index "product_specs_types", ["product_type_id", "product_spec_id"], name: "type_spec_uniq", unique: true

  create_table "product_spec_keys", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "value_id",        null: false
    t.integer "product_id"
    t.integer "product_spec_id", null: false
  end

  create_table "spec_value_booleans", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean "value", limit: 20, null: false
  end

  create_table "spec_value_numbers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "value", limit: 20, null: false
  end

  create_table "spec_value_strings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "value", limit: 20, null: false
  end
```

`products` is catalog items

`product_types` tell to product what `product_specs` it have

`product_specs_types` just join table

`spec_value_`VT is tables for keeping different types of variables

`product_spec_keys` is table for relationship between (product&it's specs) and one of `spec_value_`VT. Polymorph type key is `product_types.value_id`. And I dont know how to use it right, becouse it must to fill in all three columns at one time.

`product_type` has many `product_specs` through `product_specs_types`
`product` has many `product_specs` through `product_specs_types` - it good work (with `product_type_id` like key)

But how to make relationship like that:

```
@product.product_specs.each do |spec|
   spec.value = 'something'
   p spec.value
end
```

Where `spec.value` - is value from `spec_value_`VT (VT - is spec.value_type)

Comment: I'm really to sure what you're trying to achieve with this. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I cant't explain becouse my english is bad(((

Comment: We can't help if you can't explain :(
 Try.

Comment: I think I just confused. Maybe I need to show all models and schema.rb in question?

Comment: yes, i think that would be best